# Universal Image Loader inside RemoteViewsFactory for Android widget

Tags: android, android-widget, universal-image-loader, remoteview

I would like to publish a solution to a problem.
Hopefully it will help other people facing the same problem.

This is related to the Android Universal Image Loader library available [here](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

**Original question was :**

I started today to use your Android Universal Image Loader (AUIL) which is very very nice !
Thank you for sharing this !

I know that it is possible to use AUIL in an android widget project inside the Provider class but I'm trying to load multiples image inside a ListView (itself inside the widget).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The solution I manage to find is**

```
public class YourViewsFactory implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory
{
 Map<Integer, Boolean> flags = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>());
 Bitmap mBitmap;
 Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());


  @Override
  public RemoteViews getViewAt(final int position)
{
  final RemoteViews row = new RemoteViews(ctxt.getPackageName(), R.layout.row);
  flags.put(position, false);
  handler.post(new Runnable()
  {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        m_imgLoader.loadImage(YOUR_IMAGE_URL, new SimpleImageLoadingListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view)
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason)
            {
                flags.put(position, true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view)
            {
                flags.put(position, true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String arg0, View arg1, Bitmap bitmap)
            {
                mBitmap = bitmap;
                flags.put(position, true);
            }
        });
    }
});

while (!flags.get(position))
{
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
flags.put(position, false);
if (mBitmap != null)
{
    row.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.ivPoster, mBitmap);
} else
{
    row.setImageViewResource(R.id.ivPoster, R.drawable.cw);
}
mBitmap = null;
  } // End of getViewAt override


} // End of class
```

This is not my solution, but one of Vova Klyshevich available [here](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/199#issuecomment-18178500)!

Comment: Is this still relevant for the latest version of the library?
Why not just use loadImageSync(...) ?

Comment: when the list have about 20 elements the scrolling is unreal slow. and after some up-down cycles it crashes launcher.

Comment: @azerto00 could you please tell me how to maintain cache in your code?

Comment: Sorry @anil, it has been a long time since I didn't develop in Android nox. Can't really help you ..